# Blinking Cursor when Booting into Xen 4.1 with 3.2.0-32-generic Kernel

Tags: 12.04, server, xen

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto a machine with an AMD Athlon II x4 620 cpu, Gigabyte GA-MA785GMT-UD2H motherboard, and 16 GB of RAM.  12.04 boots fine with the 3.2.0-29-generic and 3.2.0-32-generic kernel, but after Xen 4.1 is installed and Xen is booted from the grub bootloader, the echo options are printed to the console, but then a blank screen appears with a blinking cursor.  Nothing happens after this point.

Grub options (x's replace UUID):

```
setparams 'Xen 4.1-amd64'

menuentry 'Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Xen 4.1-amd64 and Linux 3.2.0-32-generic -- class ubuntu -- class gnu -- class os -- class xen {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
echo 'Loading Xen 4.1-amd64 ...'
multiboot /xen-4.1-amd64.gz placeholder
echo "Loading Linux 3.2.0-32-generic ...'
module /vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic placeholder root=/dev/mapper/ubuntuxen-root ro
echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
module /initrd.img-3.2.0-320generic
}
```

This configuration is identical to a VirtualBox VM and the VM boots into Xen without issue.  I'm not ruling out hardware here, I am just unable to find  resources to lead me to a specific cause.

NOTE: I setup Xen using this Ubuntu community resource:
[Xen](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 possible causes:

1. You have a Nvidia graphics adapter and installed their proprietary driver on your (non-Xen) Ubuntu 12.04 install. In that case you may switch to the open-source Nouveau driver and try again booting Xen.
2. Hardware incompatibility: I had a similar issue with my Marvell SATA controller and had to disable it to boot Xen. I don't think your board has a Marvell SATA controller, but you may try to disable unused controllers, i.e. Firewire, or some additional SATA controller that's not used.